# Issue with linking a CSS file to a PUG file?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, express, pug

I'm trying to link a CSS file to a PUG file using the "link" syntax. When I try to do so, I get the following error message:

"Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/CSS/styles.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled."

- I've tried including the attribute type="text/css". It didn't work
- I tried verifying that the css file path was correct using this syntax:

```
    style
        include ../CSS/styles.css
```

This works, and allows me to ascertain that the css file path is correct. However, I want to use the "link()" syntax instead as shown in my index.pug file.

The index.pug head:

```
    head
        link(rel='stylesheet' href='../CSS/styles.css' type='text/css')
```

The app.js file:

```
    const express = require('express');
    const http = require('http');
    const path = require('path');

    const app = express();
    const viewsPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "views");
    app.set("views", viewsPath);
    app.set('view engine', 'pug');

    app.get("/", function (request, response) {
        response.render("index");
    });
    http.createServer(app).listen(3000);
```

Comment: Have you tried listing your CSS file as an absolute path instead of a relative one?

Comment: When I try it, I get the following error message: `Not allowed to load local resource: file:///D:/Google%20Drive/Projects/Dashboard/CSS/styles.css`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to server your css files as `static`. Also using `absolute paths` is preferrable when served with express.

Assuming your `Dashboard` contains only files safe to be exposed to the web.

```
app.use(express.static('Dashboard'))

// In your html, note absolute path
href='/CSS/styles.css'
```

You might also consider `virtual path` by specifying a mount point:

```
app.use('/static', express.static('Dashboard'))

// html
href='/static/CSS/styles.css'
```

Comment: I don't think I can serve pug files using the expres.static module. It works with .html files but doesn't seem to be the case for pug files it simply says: "Cannot GET /"

Comment: OH I SEE. it works now, and I didn't even have to give an absolute path. Thank you. Don't really understand why it works that way but it does...

Comment: `Don't really understand why it works`, You need to make the underlying static files available to the client by serving it. (hope it's simple)